# Generating Different Combinations of an Array of Strings [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How can I generate in **JavaScript** all the different combinations between the elements of an array of strings with the following conditions:

- The input array of strings always has different elements (no repetition);
- A different combination is always between 2 different elements
  (strings);
- The order does not matter (the combination "A" & "B" is the same as
  "B" & "A").

For instance, with this input array of strings:

```
var array = ["A", "B", "C"];
```

The different combinations would only be:

- "A" & "B" ("B" & "A" is the same combination);
- "A" & "C" ("C" & "A" is the same combination);
- "B" & "C" ("C" & "B" is the same combination).

I pretend to use it to do something like this:

```
var count = 0;
for each (different combinations in input array of strings){
   console.log (item1 of combination);
   console.log (item2 of combination);
   count = count + 1;
}
console.log(count);
```

Thank you *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work.

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C"];
var count = 0;
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   for (var j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
      console.log(arr[i] + arr[j]);
      count = count + 1;
   }
}
console.log(count);
```

Comment: Thank you * Definitely easier than I thought